# Drawing UIBezierPath with different colors in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am working with `UIBezierPath` drawing, and I want to select different colors for my path, but what is happening is that all the paths are set to the currently selected color, so how shall I resolve this issue, below is my code

```
(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if(changecolor)
    {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        strokeColor = appDelegate.color;

        SEL blackSel = NSSelectorFromString(strokeColor);
        UIColor* tColor = nil;
        if ([UIColor respondsToSelector: blackSel])
            tColor  = [UIColor performSelector:blackSel];
        [tColor setStroke];
        [tColor setFill];

        **for (UIBezierPath *_path in pathArray)      
           [_path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];**              
    }
    else
    {    
        [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
        [[UIColor redColor] setFill];

        *for (UIBezierPath *_path in pathArray)         
            [_path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];*
    }
}
```

Here my bezierpaths are in stored in an array, so please let me know how should I proceed

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: amazing you have learned so much on this topic. Great man :)

Comment: hi aalok give me your emailid

Comment: ok thanks, I will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing `UIBezierPath`s with different colors with proper **StartingPoint** and **EndingPoint** over different `CAShapeLayer`s and add those ShapeLayers to a main ShapeLayer say `self.mainShapeLayer` and then added it to your view's `layer`.

**For Eg:**
Call this method from `-drawRect` with different colors, after initializing and adding the `mainShapeLayer` to your `view`'s `layer`

```
//In drawRect
self.shapeLayer_main = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[self.layer addSubLayer:self.mainShapeLayer];


-(void)drawPathHavingStartPoint:(CGPoint )startPoint andEndPoint:(CGPoint )endPoint withColor:(UIColor *)color
{
 CAShapeLayer* shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
 //Add lineWidth, strokeColor, fillColor, path (with the points) and then add it to the mainShapeLayer
 [self.mainShapeLayer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
 }
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the color inside the loop:

```
    for (UIBezierPath *path in pathArray) {
       [myColor setStroke]
       [path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
     }
```

About naming comvention, only use _ for instance variabes, not for locals.